# Unable to sync internet account's notes

Tags: icloud, notes.app

I'm trying to sync my personal notes to my work Mac but they do not appear as an option in the internet accounts menu.
[image]

I've just installed Sonoma.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a managed Mac?

Comment: It is. Asked the IT department and they say that's not something they enforce. We use Kandji at work.

Comment: Personal opinion... keep your personal iCloud off your work devices.